# error while defining a method with 1 parameter in python

Tags: python

I try to define the function `up` with 1 parameter in class `X`, like this:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elem=[]

    def i(self, new):
        self.elem.append(new)
        self.up(self,len(self.elem)-1)                    <= error here

    def up(self, n):
        print n

border = X()

a = [2,4,3,1]

for i in a:
    border.i (i)
```

The error looks like this:

```
$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 60, in <module>
    border.i (i)
  File "prim.py", line 50, in i
    self.up(self,len(self.elem)-1)
TypeError: up() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
$
```

if I call in `i` like this `self.up(self)` , it compiles, and `print n` displays so:

```
$ <__main__.X instance at 0x7f7a7ddf0128>
<__main__.X instance at 0x7f7a7ddf0128>
<__main__.X instance at 0x7f7a7ddf0128>
<__main__.X instance at 0x7f7a7ddf0128>
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to pass `self` on to `up()`:

```
def i(self, new):
    self.elem.append(new)
    self.up(len(self.elem)-1)
```

Python does this for you; by looking up `self.up`, you are given a *bound method*, which means that Python will *automatically* add in `self` when you call `up()`.

You were, in effect, calling `up(self, self, len(self.elem)-1)`; three elements where only 2 were expected.

Comment: Hm. I did not think to ! I had in mind inheritance, when I call the constructor of the parent class with `self` ! Thanks.

Comment: @alinsoar: When you retrieve a *unbound* method from the class, you do need to do that. But from an *instance* you get yourself a *bound* method and then it all works automatically.

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to pass self to the method. It's done by python directly

That is one of the reason we use classes and methods: you dont explicit pass the object, since it is inside a class and that particular instance is therefore used

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `self` explicitly:

```
self.up(self, len(self.elem)-1)
        ^^^^^ this needs to be removed
```

When I make this change and run your program, I get

```
0
1
2
3
```